# Error headers: ap_headers_output_filter() after putting cache header in htaccess file

Tags: apache-2.2, php, .htaccess, cache, linux

Receiving error:

> [debug] mod_headers.c(663): headers: ap_headers_output_filter()

after I included this within the `.htaccess` file:

```
# 6 DAYS
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=518400, public"
</FilesMatch>
 
# 2 DAYS
<FilesMatch "\.(xml|txt)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=172800, public, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
 
# 2 HOURS
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

Any help is appreciated as to what I could do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Generally since this is a debug level error/notice, you can turn it off in Apache config (perhaps `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/somesite`, `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` or `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` or perhaps a `.htaccess` file) by setting a line to:

```
LogLevel warn
```

as opposed to:

```
LogLevel debug
```

Comment: "or perhaps a `.htaccess` file" - You can't actually set this in `.htaccess`, it needs to be in the main server config or virtualhost.